EventBus with undeploy verticle
This is a code example：
public class EventTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        var vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.eventBus().consumer("address", message -> {
            vertx.executeBlocking(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
                message.reply("Sleeping done.");
                return null;
            }, false);
        });

        vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
                    @Override
                    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
                        getVertx().eventBus().consumer("event", message -> {
                            System.out.println("Received Event msg:" + message.body());
                            latch.countDown();
                            getVertx().eventBus()
                                    .request("address", "hello")
                                    .onComplete(
                                            m -> System.out.println("Received reply message: " + m.body()),
                                            Throwable::printStackTrace
                                    );
                        });

                        super.start(startPromise);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void stop(Promise<Void> stopPromise) throws Exception {
                        super.stop(stopPromise);
                    }
                }, new DeploymentOptions())
                .onComplete(
                        id -> {
                            Thread.ofPlatform().start(() -> {
                                vertx.eventBus().publish("event", "Hello World");
                                try {
                                    latch.await();
                                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

                                Thread.ofPlatform().start(() -> vertx.undeploy(id).onComplete(event -> System.out.println("Undeployed")));
                            });
                        },
                        Throwable::printStackTrace
                );
    }
}

When a Verticle is processing an EventBus event and is simultaneously undeployed, it causes the callback interface not to be invoked (it will not output "Received reply message: Sleeping done."). How can I ensure that the callback completes execution before the Verticle is fully undeployed?
expected System.out.println: "Received reply message: Sleeping done."
